# Is it possible to create a Home control Actions to control Non-Android TV?

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible to create a Home control Actions to control Non-Android TV?
Just like Amazon Smart Home Skills for Entertainment Devices to turn on/off TV, change channel, switch input source, change volume, control playback...

I did not found these types associated with TV in smart home device types.
This is described in the document:

> The functionality for device types comes from the traits that you add to each one. Each device type has a number of recommended traits, but you can add whichever ones you want.

How do I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you watched the [smart home talk at I/O](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h44p9IOaDwo), you will see that supporting media devices and traits are currently in development. Although they are not ready for every developer yet, you will see the content show up in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) when it is available.

In the short-term, you can assign a different device type for your TV, like `LIGHT`. The types are used primarily for semantics, like "turn off my lights". You may be able to use some of the traits as they currently exist. For example, a [handful of modes](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs/issues/85) are designed for media-type devices.